# JSON/XML serialization: Ignore/include some fields from the base class

Tags: c#, xml, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

In `Web API` JSON and XML Media-Type Formatters (and especially serializers) [could be configured](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_media_type_formatter) with `[JsonIgnore]` or `[DataMember]` decorators.

It works for the methods fields only, but what about the base class? Is there a way to ignore or include some fields of it?

And if there is no - what is the best approach to control the visibility of the 
class fields in the serialized output? Defining specified JSON/XML serializers? Converting class object to another class object with selected fields in the `Controller`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a DTO that is specific for your current action and then copy the data from the DTO to the actual object you want to use.

Benefits of this is you can define validation that are specific to this action and you'll have no attributes on the business object. You can use different validation rules per action for each new DTO and still use the same business object.

If you don't want to write the mapping code to map from the DTO to the business object you can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Example code:

```
public enum ColourType
{
  Flat,
  Metallic
}

public class Car
{
  public void Repaint(int red, int green, int blue, ColourType colourType)
  {
    // TODO: Add some validation logic and business logic.
  }
}

public class RepainInMetallicModel
{
  [Required]
  [Range(0, 100)]
  public int Red { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [Range(0, 100)]
  public int Green { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [Range(0, 100)]
  public int Blue { get; set; }
}

public class RepaintInFlatModel
{
  [Required]
  [Range(0, 255)]
  public int Red { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [Range(0, 255)]
  public int Green { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [Range(0, 255)]
  public int Blue { get; set; }
}

public class CarController
{
  public ActionResult RepaintInMetallic(RepainInMetallicModel model)
  {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      var car = _carsRepository.Find(model.Id);

      var.Repaint(model.Red, model.Green, model.Blue, ColourType.Metallic);

      _carsRepository.Save(car);
    }

    return View();
  }

  public ActionResult RepaintInFlat(RepaintInFlatModel model)
  {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      var car = _carsRepository.Find(model.Id);

      var.Repaint(model.Red, model.Green, model.Blue, ColourType.Flat);

      _carsRepository.Save(car);
    }

    return View();
  }
}
```

The following example doesn't demonstrate the usage of [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/), but it does demonstrate the usage of DTOs.

Comment: not sure that this answer is really helpful, but anyway - **DTO** and **AutoMapper** could be a possible solutions here. There is a nice blog post which helps me a lot : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/using-web-api-with-entity-framework,-part-6